# MySQL Between Like for dates

Tags: mysql, sql

The following works:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-10-05' AND '2015-12-31';`

However I tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-10%' AND '2015-12%';`

This doesn't work is there a way to select two dates with a wildcard in it?

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE year(date_created) BETWEEN 2014 AND 2015 AND month(date_created) BETWEEN 10 AND 12`

I also tried it doing like above, that also doesn't select a range it just selects everything that is `2014` and `2015` and everything that only has the month `10` and `12`.

Is there a way I can make the following work?

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-10%' AND '2015-12%';`

Comment: What would you expect `BETWEEN '2014-10%' AND '2015-12%'` to mean? Surely you just mean `BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-12-31'`?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-12-31'`?

Comment: I'm trying in JavaFX to show a chart and I use two datepickers one where you can enter a `start date` and the other for the `end date` so someone can enter something like `2014-10-05` and `2015-12-02`. I was hoping that I could get a range of months just in SQL so I didn't have to find the last day of the month in java.  Because doing this: `BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-12-31'` I need the nr of days of the month entered in `end date datepicker`

Comment: MySQL has a `LAST_DAY` function that returns the last date of a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function to get the last day of the month of a date.

```
WHERE date_created BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-05', '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY('2015-12-02')
```

This is better than the solution that uses `DATE_FORMAT` on the `date_created` column because it can make use of an index on that column.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DATE_FORMAT for this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_created,"%Y-%m") BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-05',"%Y-%m") AND DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-31',"%Y-%m") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

While @GoudaElalfy solution does the job, there may be an issue of performance with that query. It wouldn't use a simple index on column `date_created`.

---

Refering to your comment in which you state that actually what you need is a way to build a query that covers entire months:

> I was hoping that I could get a range of months just in SQL so I didn't have to find the last day of the month in java. Because doing this:  BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-12-31' I need to know the nr of day of the last month.

You could compute those values and leave the column in the `WHERE` clause so that it does benefit from a simple index on it.

1. You know that there is a first day for every month, and this would be your starting point to scan the index/table.
2. You need to compute the last day of a month because it's not static, and that would be your ending point in table/index scanning process.

One way to do this is using [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-05', '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY('2015-12-31');
```

Second way would be using some straightforward calculations

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-05', '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-31' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not a good Idea to use a Function an a field from the table in the WHERE Clause "DATE_FORMAT(date_created,"%Y-%m")". So the Database MUST do the function on each row in the Table. This will a full Table scan.

i Have create a test table with 3000 rows. Here is the execution Plan of this Query where you can see that they read all (3000) rows.

```
MariaDB > EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_created BETWEEN
    -> DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-05',"%Y-%m") AND DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-31',"%Y-%m") ;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | myTable | index | date_created  | date_created | 4       | NULL | 3000 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

it will be better to build the start and end Condition as Constant like this

**to create the start date:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-05','%Y-%m-01');
```

**to create the end date:**

add one month, set on the first of month, sub 1 second

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-07' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01') -INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%y-%m-%d');
```

**And the full query is this:**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_created
  BETWEEN
    DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-05','%Y-%m-01')
  AND
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-07' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    -INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%y-%m-%d');
```

and in the execution plan you can see that they use the index and only selects 177 row

```
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | myTable | range | date_created  | date_created | 4       | NULL |  177 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```